# Any difference in performance/compatibility of different languages in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

In nowadays the PostgreSQL [offers plenty  of procedural languages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/xplang.html): pl/pgsql, pl/perl, etc

Are there any difference in the speed/memory consumption in procedures written in different languages?

Does anybody have done any test?

Is it true that to use the native pl/pgsql is the most correct choice?

How the procedure written in C++ and compiled into loadable module differs in all parameter w.r.t. the user function written with pl/* languages?

Comment: I would be interested in the same answers just for python.

Comment: I don't really see how your question is effectively answerable. Of course there a differences in speed/memory consumption that are unique too those languages and their implementation. I personally use plpythonu only because I use python. I could care less if it runs twice as slow as pl/perl as long as it runs fast enough. The main benefit being it provides the libraries I am already using.

Comment: I see Nate, but if you have a procedure which runs 5 secs and with the other language it runs 10 secs, so in the second case you'll need to reconsider you db structure since 5 secs is acceptable but not 10 in real life.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct choice depends on what exactly you're going to do.

In my experience, pl/pgsql has less overhead than say pl/perl, pl/python or pl/tcl, *if* what you want to do is easily expressde in pl/pgsql. For example, if you're doing database operations. However, the overhead you pay for example for pl/perl quickly comes back if you do something that perl is good at - such as for example string processing.

The one thing you have to think of in those cases are that the "bigger" languages like perl and python have a significantly higher startup cost than pl/pgsql - but that can easily be mitigated by using persistent connections.

Functions written in C will almost certainly be faster - and they'll use less memory if you can write code that is good at using little memory. However, the overheard of writing and maintaining them is usually a *lot* worse than the PLs - in particularly constructing and deconstructing tuples will take a lot more code than you think in any kind of complex functions.

The only PL style language I've found significantly slower than the others is pl/java, due to the JVM overhead. But I'm sure you can find cases where it's faster for some problems.

If you want to be sure of what's absolutely most efficient in *your* scenario, you need to develop a couple of your functions in each language and then benchmark those. But chances are it doesn't really matter and you can pick whichever language suits the task best from a development perspective rather than a performance one.

Comment: "But chances are it doesn't really matter and you can pick whichever language suits the task best from a development perspective rather than a performance one." Yup. As with most programming questions about choosing a platform for performance reasons, most of the time there is more to gain from choosing a platform the developers prefer and throwing hardware at performance deficiencies.